# Application Root Operator (~) problem with Virtual Directory in IIS 6.0

Tags: iis-6, asp.net-4.0

I have a web application that runs fine locally, but when I move it to a virtual directory on the web server (let's call it "VirDir"), it adds the directory name to the relative path.

For example, if I try to access ~/Default.aspx, it will tell me that it cannot find /VirDir/VirDir/Default.aspx.

Is it something boneheaded, or do I just have to use absolute addressing to make it work (if I try to access /Default.aspx, it finds it fine)?

Answer (score 0):

That's the way it is... Use absolute addressing as /default.aspx.

Might help explain your case:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1521537.aspx

Take a look here to better understand iis 6 and virtual directories:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwk103ab.aspx